# Attaching container's directory to host volume in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have created a persistent volume on my host system at location `/dynamic_data`. I have a test container which has some data present at location `/shared`. I want to bind the `/shared` with the persistent volume at `/dynamic_data`. Now, `/shared` already has many files inside it and I want them to be reflected at `/dynamic_data`. The problem is that `/dynamic_data` contains nothing and the same is reflected inside the container, i.e., I loose my data inside the container because nothing was present in the host directory. Is there any way this problem can be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently persistent volume doesn't do overlaying.  If you "mount" the pv to your container, you will only see what the host initially has, which in your case its empty.

My 2 cents...
If you need to persist the /shared from your container, 
- first mount the pv to a different path in your container say /dyanamic-data.

- Then  start your container/pod
- then exec into the pod
- from there you can copy /shared to /dyanmic-data.
- So now you have your files present on both container /shared and the pv.
- Shutdown your app, mount your pv to /shared then you will be able to persist your files outside the container.

All these will require downtime unfortunately.